# Swing applications are slower on Java 11+ Linux

Tags: java, swing, java-8, java-11

When upgrading a Java 8 Swing application to run on Java 11 we noticed the startup and UI interaction were roughly 2x slower.

This is when running using XServer 1.15.1, Linux kernel 3.17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a lot of research and running profiling we discovered that Java 11 somehow has calls to XServer that are 2x slower than the same Java 8 calls.

The solution was to upgrade XServer to 1.18+